# No Method Error in Profiles New

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is supposed to allow you to create a profile after you sign up and click the "Create user Profile" link. But for some reason the below error shows up instead of my form field page.

EDIT:
Error raised:

```
undefined method `first_name' for #<Profile id: nil>
```

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/saasapp/app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
```

Please help. I am not sure where I went wrong. I am taking a course on upskillcourses.com and I followed along with the video and I even copied the code and pasted it in to the file just in case the first two times I typed it out by hand was incorrect.

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'pages#home'
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
resources :users do
   resource :profile 
end
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
resources :contacts, only: [:create]
get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'
```

end

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170314180155) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: Looks like your `Profile` model doesn't have a `first_name` field. Did you create a migration to add the `first_name`, `last_name` fields?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add your routes.rb and the link tag?

Comment: The link tag to what?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Profile` model doesn't have `first_name` field. Since you didn't get the "migration" error, I can only assume you need to add those 2 fields in a separate migration as a task in your online course...

As per OP's comments:

```
# Add missing columns to profiles table
rails generate migration AddFirstNameAndLastNameToProfile first_name last_name

# Run migration
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: How would I add them to the migration file? It shows them on my schema.rb. I posted that in my question if you need to see it.

Comment: Yeap, you did something wrong while generating the `Profile` model. As you can see, you don't have any fields in your "profiles" table.

Comment: Yea I see that. How would I go about fixing that? I tried to run the rails db:migrate command again but it didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: So I deleted my migration file and then I created a new one. I added all the correct information for my table. But now I am getting an error saying that the profiles table already exists. How do I remove it?

Comment: Before deleting your migration, you should have rolled back your migrations so that rails undos the migration (`rails db:rollback`). Please read the guide on [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).